# Shortcodes for non-wordpress custom CMS

Tags: php, dry, shortcode

Trying to implement my own "shortcode"-type system on my cms.

`substr()` can possibly work as long as there isn't more than one shortcode in the content.  I can't use `<?php` `?>`, but must use a `WYSIWYG` type editor for entering in the shortcode, since it is the enduser who will be entering them via the content editor.

If someone enters a "Shortcode" that follows the rules I set, this class function will discover the shortcode, parse it and then replace the shortcode with other data pulled from mysql or another source.

I can get this to work, essentially no problem, if there is not more than one single shortcode entered into the content via `WYSIWYG`, but more than one and it breaks.

I've looked all over the internet for this and found various things, but most of them deal with `Wordpress` and the few that don't aren't approaching it as I need to.  Found one threat on `StackOverflow` which provides a potential approach that I could use, but I really need advice and a place to start more than a full function.  The `Wordpress` Shortcode system isn't helpful either.

Comment: You could try to use regex.

Comment: @AntoineB until you want nested shortcodes at which point it becomes an unresolvable nightmare. OP you're not going to want to write this [a full-fledged parser] yourself, I strongly suggest looking for a library that handles this.

Comment: I agree getting shortcodes right can be complex, the parser is normally done with finite state machine and lots of recursion if you are familiar with that stuff you can give it a shot.

Comment: I'm still looking at how Wordpress does this.  There appear to be several functions doing it.  In the past I would just create a "plugin" for my CMS and if the enduser enables that plugin on a page (via form), that plugin's content and features overrides the whole page or is appended at the end of the main content.  It'd be really cool though if I could make plugin content appear in the middle of page content, sort of like Wordpress, to allow more flexibility.